# Nginx does not redirect proxied responses correct

Tags: nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy

I have a running nginx instance on server A which passes requests to an Apache webserver on server B.

I have tested several(!) settings... but the following problem still remains:

A request like `https://example.com/myapp` gets *translated* to `http://example.com/` and *passed* to server B.
Server B sends a `http://example.com/login` response to nginx/server A. But nginx does not translate that response to `https://example.com/myapp/login`: what I receive if I use `wget https://example.com/myapp` is `https://example.com/login` (which lacks of the `/myapp` part).

That's my current config:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
    
  server_name example.com;
  location /myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.100/;
  }
}
```

I have read many threads and played with many parameters like `proxy_redirect`, `rewrite` and `return`. But that did not worked for me...

Comment: "Server B sends a https://example.com/login response" - do you mean a 3xx status response? Use `curl -I` to identify the exact content of the `Location` response header, because you will need that to make `proxy_redirect` work. Meanwhile, you should be using `location /myapp/` (with a trailing `/`) otherwise your URLs will not be translated correctly.

Comment: `curl -I` gives me:
`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`
`Location: https://example.com/myapp/`

I was already using the trailing `/`. The posted code was just for testing.

Comment: That's not `https://example.com/login` as stated in your question.

Comment: `https://example.com/login` is what i receive with `wget` (See edited question). But `https://example.com/myapp/` is still the expected/correct **location,** right? But it is not the expected **Response-URL**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to reconfigure server B rather than reconfiguring Nginx.  When server B issues a redirect, it needs to include the directory.   You can pass headers to the backend to let it know that it is behind a reverse proxy and then change the backend to redirect differently when it detects those headers:

```bash
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

As far as I know, Nginx has no equivalent of Apache's [`proxypass_reverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directive which munges the redirect headers from the backend server.  So another solution would be to switch from Nginx to Apache for the front end which has the functionality to change the redirect.